# How to run a thread again in a thread or initialise that thread

Tags: java

Basically I have the code

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run(){
        if(close==true){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,”ok”);
        else{
             t1.run();
        }
    }
});
```

But where it says t1.run it says variable t1 might not have been initialised. So is there another way to make the thread run again in that else place or is there a way to initialise it close is a Boolean variable. Thank you

Comment: Use `this.run()` or replace it with a loop.

Comment: Oh it was that simple thank you so much

Comment: Um... you're not starting the thread using `t1.run()` are you? You should be using `t1.start()`

Comment: Just to be sure: you know that you should not be using bare metal threads? You know that you have to call start() on your threads? You know that swing is basically single threaded and using your own thread to update ui elements can result in strange effects?

Comment: Ok changed it from .run to .start

Comment: Please use `if (close)` instead of `if (close == true)` since `close` is `boolean` itself

Comment: @ivan oh ok does it do the same thing

Comment: @Callum, yes it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `t1` with `this`.

```
this.run() // recursive
```

If this runs long enough, you will eventually run out of stack space. To get around this, you should wrap everything in a loop. This way, it won't create the exception of this website's namesake (`StackOverflowException`).

```
while (!close) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ok");
}
```

Comment: Recursive call will of course eventually run out of stack space.

Comment: Seems to be a REALLY BAD idea to use a recursive call (it should be a valid use case, but this doesn't seem to be one). Use with care.

Comment: And just to be really clear: the one and only approach is to use a loop. The idea of a recursive call is plain wrong, end of story.

Comment: So I shouldn’t use a recursive call I should use a loop isn’t that doing the same thing just repeating the code till it equals true

Comment: I used a recursive call but added a pause of 1tenth of a second